# Asp.net Page throws Site cannot be reached

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis

I have very strange issue, when when I press the **asp.net button click event page is keep loading**(in chrome **it shows  *uploading(43%))*, after 5-6 minutes shows below**

This Application works perfect in development server.(where I have only this application in the IIS) and in Production environment and get this error

This mostly happens with Postback events(uploading files & etc).

[image]

I have been searching for a solution for few days nothing success and  the most of the articles are said **check the DNS/Proxy** server and **increasing request timeout from web.config**

But as I feel this is related to something else.

Is number of  SQL database request affecting on this matter?

Comment: Use your browser's developer tools or Fiddler to track the post back HTTP request and see where it goes.

Comment: Could you please tell us the file size you have upload to the server?  I guess this issue is related with the file upload event hangs.  I suggest you could also use the remote debug to remote debug the upload postback event to find out the actually reason. Details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-aspnet-on-a-remote-iis-7-5-computer?view=vs-2019).

Comment: @BrandoZhang file is less than 1 mb, although we have increased the upload limit from the web.config

Comment: As lex and my previous comment , you should use F12 to make sure the request path is right and using the remote debug to debug the event to check if there is any related error has been thrown.

Comment: @BrandoZhang this happens randomly, not all the time, I suspect this is related Application pool or Database connection pool. This application is not well designed and it coded as ASP.net Website project.